# StatefulWidget:Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator

Tags: dart, flutter, statefulwidget

I am trying to create a sample and I am trying to create a navigation from a `statefulWidget`, I am getting the below error, most of the samples talk about navigation between stateless widgets

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
flutter: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
flutter: The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a
flutter: descendant of a Navigator widget.
```

below is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/second.dart';

main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var strings = ["Flutter", "Java", "SWift"];
  var displayText = "";

  void onPressed() {
    var list = List<int>.generate(3, (int index) => index); // [0, 1, 4]
    list.shuffle();
    print(list);

    setState(() {
      displayText = strings[list.first];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var scaffold = Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Second'),
      ),
      body: Container(
          child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              displayText,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 30.0),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Change'),
              textColor: Colors.black,
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second'); // Fails here
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      )),
    );
    return MaterialApp(
      home: scaffold,
      routes: {
        '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Below is what I have tried

1. Used Navigator.of(context)
2. Wrapped the `statefulwidget` as a home of a material app created from a statelesswidget.

but no luck.

Comment: all the solution talk about stateless widgets... somehow I am unable to apply the solutioins stated ...into the statefulwidgets....

Comment: The solutions are unrelated to stateless/stateful

Comment: Ok...but I am somehow not able figure it out. my widget code is in the state class, you want me to move it to a different class? I tried to do some of the solutions and I end up in some or the other issues...am new to Flutter and learning by creating sample apps, so if you can give me some pointers based on my code it would be great

Comment: The easiest is to add a `Builder` above `Container`

Comment: Great Thanks man...it worked...you can add as an answer if you want and I can mark it

Comment: Just put an upvote on the linked answer from the duplicate :)

Comment: Sure I will do that